# RestSharp to httpwebrequest converting process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a api call to "https://api.getresponse.com/v3" with header **"X-Auth-Token: api-key jfgs8jh4ksg93ban9Dfgh8"** i already did it with RestSharp library bellow but somehow this not works. So i want to try same thing with httpwebrequest. Please provide an example same request using httpwebrequest i am new to c# that's why need help. Thanks in advance

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://api.getresponse.com/v3");
 var request = new RestRequest("/campaigns/", Method.POST);

 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token:", "api-key 948dff91a017a07f3c6");
 request.Parameters.Clear();

 var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: We'd be happy to help with a specific problem you have trying it yourself but SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: You should try to specify more accurately how exactly it "does not work". An ordinary request should most likely work without problems with RestSharp. You can use some tool to trace the request and figure out if all parameter, headers etc. are set correctly. Then you'll know where the problem lies

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035813/getresponse-com-add-email-to-list-using-api-call see here. I was opened another question but no one able to answer it. I am having getresponse.com authorization issue with RestSharp

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to send a header, but you do

```
request.AddParameter("X-Auth-Token:", "api-key 948dff91a017a07f3c6");
```

Moreover you do `Parameters.Clear` after that. Maybe changing this to `AddHeader` will work?

Otherwise, please provide us with more details on what exactly does not work.

Comment: my bad, have updated to AddHeader. Can you help me converting it to httpwebrequest?

Comment: Have not worked with it much, but why would you need that?

Comment: getresponse.com made with php and somehow they wanted php c url equipment call so on c# as i know httpwebrequest is c url equipment thats why wanted to try it

Comment: There is no difference on how you call an endpoint. PostSharp is probably using HttpWebRequest behind the scenes as well. For as long as all headers and parameters are in place server cannot tell how the request was made.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ncjUuw check the picture here. i am getting wrong header error. https://apidocs.getresponse.com/en/v3/errors/1021 here error details

Comment: Maybe you should not do .Clear? Should not really clear headers, but who knows. I can't help you too much with details, not a super specialist on RestSharp. From the error it seems that headers are not really set corretly